# Adding a seperate class to list items parent using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list with different levels of depth:

```
<ul id="top-level" class="top-level">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub item 1</li>
      <li>Sub item 2</li>
      <li>Sub item 3
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Subsub item 1</li>
          <li>Subsub item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Sub item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following jquery script to add a class to the parents:

```
$("ul li ul").parent().addClass("menuparent");
```

Is there a way to add this class only to the top level parent `li`'s and a different class for all other (deeper) parent `li`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For top level `li`s

```
$("#top-level > li").addClass("menuparent");
```

and for lower level `li`

```
$("#top-level li li").addClass("someotherclass");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `>` selector from your top level `ul`.

Based on your current selector:

```
$("ul.top-level > li > ul").parent().addClass("menuparent");
```

Or for `li` only:

```
$("ul.top-level > li").parent().addClass("menuparent");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, people are not giving you answers for locating the deeper **parent** li's, here's my take:

```
$("ul.top-level > li > ul").find('li > ul').parent().addClass("deeper-parent-li");
```